# Disable closing a QT application

Tags: shortcut-keys, qt

I have a minimal iso with openbox and a program in QT in full screen mode. The program must be on top; I got rid of the minimize, maximize and close buttons in qwidget, but the user can still close the program by using alt-F4. I checked the settings in Unity Control Center, but it does not have any alt-F4 keys to cancel. There is another key too, alt-ctrl-F1, which opens the full screen terminal.

What I want is either user is working with my program or turning off the computer, no closing my program. It would be ok even if I could get rid of close sequence from QT itself.

Is there any way I can get rid of these shortcuts?

Comment: I think you want a 'kiosk'. You can search the internet for kiosks, for example Porteus Kiosk, that can be configured for different purposes, http://porteus-kiosk.org/

Comment: well it is for an embedded system , the program must control some relay and ... things , but having internet is not crucial at all

Comment: you know in some programs just chrome , when to press the alt f4 it dose not close , it just ask a yes or no and then quits , even if i could do that with my qt and , so the qt peogram ignores the alt f4 or any closing signal , that would work too !

Comment: You should perhaps take a look at Ubuntu Core and running your app with mir-kiosk support there. https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/examples/snaps-on-mir